# Junit fails- quotes in String comparing

Tags: java, junit4

I am trying to compare 2 String in `assertEquals` using `JUnit 4`, `Java 8`, to check decryption function, so:

```
String data = "veryLongEncryptedString.....";
String value = DecUtils.decryptToken(data, null); //returns String
assertEquals("Here User name: ", "encrypt expected value", value);
```

The values are equal but the console shows one of them quoted:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: Here is test for Addition Result:  expected:<[xxx]> but was:<["xxx"]>
```

How do make both values quoted or unquoted?
Thanks.

Comment: You can remove the first and last characters by doing `str = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);`

Comment: use escape chars "\"xxx\""

Comment: @pkpnd at which point you are no longer comparing the entire message

Comment: shouldn't you take a look at your `decryptToken` function if it's not returning what you expect?

Comment: `assertEquals` simply calls equals on the Strings.. If you are expecting the output: `<["xxx"]>` then maybe your String to compare should be of this form... If you were expecting `a` as output you would not try to assertEqual that to `b` would you?

Comment: @Stultuske Maybe I don't understand the question. Given the `ComparisonFailure` message, one string is surrounded by quotes and the other isn't. So to "make both values unquoted" you'd strip quotes off the quoted string, no?

Comment: @pkpnd yes, but since those quotes are part of the message to be tested, they shouldn't be stripped, they should be added to the message to compare with. what if you wanted to re-use this comparison code for Strings where none of the two has quotes?

Comment: @Stultuske But your what-if is an entirely different question. In OP's question, one string has quotes, and another doesn't, and OP wants to assert equality ignoring the quotes.

Comment: @pkpnd "How do make both values quoted or unquoted?" so no, he's not trying to ignore the quotes. your suggestion can indeed work, assuming he'll not put his assertions in a re-usable method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do make both values quoted or unquoted?

The idea of a `assertEquals` test is to compare an exact expected value with the output of a method.  Here, the `DecUtils.decryptToken` is providing a string that *already* *contains* open and close quotes.  So you have two choices:

- Those quotes are expected as part of the return value, so you should change the test string to be the correct expected value:

  `String data = "\"veryLongEncryptedString.....\"";`
- Those quotes are *not* expected as part of the return value:  The test is failing because it *should* be failing, and you have to fix the decryptToken routine so it returns the correct result.

Which one of those to do depends on the documentation for `DecUtils.decryptToken`, but please note that you should do only one!

Answer (score 1):

AssertEqual won't work for the reason mentioned above.
For strings comparisson I am using hamcrest which can for an assertion like the following:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;  


assertThat("encrypt expected value", equalTo("encrypt expected value"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using any library you can create an expected String and assert

```
String result = "xxx";
assertEquals(value, "\"" + result + "\"");
```